# Dell Latitude 5490 BIOS update broke Ubuntu

Tags: dell, bios

After [updating BIOS from version 1.0.8 to 1.1.9](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=JP8NT) preinstalled Ubuntu stopped loading (black screen) on my Dell Latitude 5490. Live iso Ubuntu 16.04 LTS also does not load. BIOS downgrade is blocked by vendor.

How can I recover from this?

Comment: Seeing this as well. Tried to upgrade to 18.04 but it didn't work either

Comment: Support answered, my warranty is not apply to the software and its compability is ensured by Ubuntu Community. I am not the one facing this problem: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Lattitude-5490-kernel-4-15-black-screen-inteldrmfb-i915-modeset/td-p/6037885 Vendor doesn't comment on the current situation.

Comment: This patch to the linux kernel seems to fix the problem: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10003565/. Taken from here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105549#c30

Answer (score 2):

DELL fix this issue today in 1.2.3 BIOS version

Comment: Can you please add instructions needed to fix the situation when neither Ubuntu nor Live ISO works?

Comment: Just install this BIOS version http://www.dell.com/support/home/ru/ru/rubsdc/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=9PP33

Comment: I had the same problem. Upgrade the BIOS to 1.2.3 version fixed the issue for me

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.